Suggesting SE sites for off-topic questions
I can't remember and I can't find the answer - though this has certainly been asked:
Is flagging a question the appropriate way to suggest an appropriate SE site for off-topic questions?

For interest: We occasionally get quite severe adverse reactions from mods on other SE sites when we migrate a question in good faith.

Flagging for migration is rarely ever the correct action, save for the case when someone asks something on the main site that belongs here on meta. Then close/flag for closure -> community-specific reason -> belongs on another site -> belongs on meta.
The reason why flagging + migration is rarely ever the correct thing is because both you and the moderator carrying out the migration must be certain that the question is on-topic at the target site as-is and that it will be well-received there. We should not migrate crap, or things that may be received as crap at the target site.
Knowing what's on-topic elsewhere is hardly ever the case across the network - I'd say that the majority of post migrations fail. Resulting in a poorly-received question, often bad to the point where it will get closed on the new site, resulting in even more pointless busy-work moderation.
It is better to leave a comment suggesting that the question may be better received elsewhere, let the OP read what's on-topic at that other site and then re-adjust and re-post their question accordingly. Or if they are certain, ask on the other site's meta. Also, it's hardly rocket science to copy/paste text and ask a new question elsewhere.
In case the question is off-topic here, also close vote/flag for closing.

Yes, flag it for moderator attention. It would be good to check the site and ensure it is on topic for the other site.
(Also DIY is a home improvement site, which is community misunderstood here)

Haha, you caught that? No problem. They had an HVAC tag, and I poked around a little and saw a few questions along the same line so it looked like a fit. But I get it; moves by moderators need to be more precise than general user questions.

There is a close option for that purpose, though only Stacks you are member of can be selected.
A comment would be the alternative, whether to kindly hint the OP in that direction, or in the hope that a user who is a member of the relevant Stack can perform the close action, depending on how important/relevant closing the question is.

Ah, that explains why my list of options is so limited. Thanks!
